# Trying to create a hero image using reactjs and semantic ui

Tags: html, css, reactjs, semantic-ui

I am trying to create a website with a hero image at the top of the page using a combination of React and Semantic UI (just what I learnt on the course I took).

This is the component:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div class='ui inverted vertical masthead center aligned segment'>
            <div class='ui text container'>
                <h1 class='ui inverted header'>My name</h1>
                <h2>My role</h2>
                <div class='ui huge primary button'>
                    Get Started <i class='right arrow icon'></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.ui.masthead {
    padding: 10%;
    background-image: url('../../assets/space.jpg') !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

This shows the following:
[Small screen webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGspj.png)

Which is fine but then when I expand the page I get the following:

[large screen webpage with black bar on the side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8xrn.png)

How can I stop the black bar on the side? I would have thought the image would just resize to be larger to fit the page rather than show the black background colour.

I have tried to add `width: 100%` but get the same issue.

Comment: Can you replicate that issue using this? https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: Hi, I've tried to replicate the issue on here but can't seem to get the background to even show up :(  https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-rgb-24zkk?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: Okay I replaced the image: https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-shannon-ufke6?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark but the output is like what you want.

Comment: Thanks for looking into that  - I've uploaded the image online and used that in codepen but like you mentioned @ManojKumar, it seems to show up fine. However I did try to run my app again today but I'm still getting the same issue locally so not sure what the problem could be here. I also tried the image you used in my local environment and also got the same issue but it happened when I extended the screen to be wider this time, so maybe it's to do with the size of the image?

Comment: So after playing around with it a bit, it seems to be the `segment` classname of semantic ui which causes the issue, though again, not sure how to fix it. Ideally I would like to keep the classname there as it also applies other styling (such as centering the text on the image)

Comment: I see it completely: https://nimb.ws/T1ZAjH So it is tough to help you without seeing the issue.

Comment: Hmmm thanks for trying Manoj. It's really weird - it seems to work fine on codepen but not on my local machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so weirdly for some reason the exact code I posted worked fine on Codepen, but wouldn't work on my local machine.

However, I've somehow managed to get it to work by adding a `.segment` selector to my CSS (so I'm assuming it's a styling thing with the segment causing the issue) so my CSS now looks like this:

```
.ui.masthead.segment {
    padding: 10%;
    background-image: url("../../assets/space.jpg") !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

which has it working properly.

Thanks to anyone who tried to help!